# parse-server push for multiple apps?

Tags: node.js, adapter, parse-server

We are trying to implement push to applications, using [parse-server-push-adapter](https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-server-push-adapter) over [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server).
We migrated our apps from parse.com.

Our problem is that we have multiple apps using the same mongodb with a single hosted parse sever (hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk).

The current push configuration allows to provide only one certificate but we have several apps with several apple certificates that we need to push to from that server, based on appIdentifier (as is possible on  parse.com)

Has anyone solved a similar problem?

Any suggestions on how to tackle that?

Answer (score 0):

If you will look on [parse-server push notification entry](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push) it mentioned there that you can add array of certificates for dev, prod etc.
in this array you need to specify your **p12** certificate location, prefix and **bundleId** so there try to add multiple certificates with different bundleIds

From the wiki:

> For iOS, if you need to support both the dev and prod certificates,
>   you can provide an array of configurations like

```
 push: {
    ios: [
      {
        pfx: '', // Dev PFX or P12
        bundleId: '',
        production: false // Dev
      },
      {
        pfx: '', // Prod PFX or P12
        bundleId: '',  
        production: true // Prod
      }
    ]
  }
```